# Duplicating carrierwave image

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a model called Book which has a cover_image.

```
mount_uploader :cover_image, BookPixUploader
```

And the uploader is declared as follows:

```
class BookPixUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or ImageScience support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  CarrierWave::Uploader::ExtensionWhitelist
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # include CarrierWave::ImageScience

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "system/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  ....
```

I am trying to save a new book:

```
newbook = book.dup 
newbook.save
```

But It's not uploading a new image to amazon S3.

I have tried:

```
newbook = book.dup
newbook.cover_image = book.cover_image
newbook.save
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I dont want to change store_dir.

Comment: Any validation on Book if any :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newbook = book.dup
newbook.remote_cover_image_url = book.cover_image.url
newbook.save
```

If this doesn't work, you may want to look into duplicating the attributes another way, since `book.dup` could do weird things to the uploader.

Comment: It works,,, but.. The thumbnails are not preserved. I ended up by manually copying the entire folder using aws-s3 and executing a sql query to update cover_image string field in the database.

Comment: Strange. I'd expect carrierwave to generate a new thumbnail from the (as far as it knows) new upload. If you want to avoid the manual s3 & sql work, in case `dup` has confused carrierwave, you could experiment with manually copying the attributes with something like `newbook.attributes = book.attributes.except('id', 'cover_image')` (you may also need to clear out other fields as well).

Comment: The thumbnails were not as straightforward as usual, they were cropped following runtime variables which were set when creating the original book.

Comment: I see. In that case, if you can duplicate the runtime variables, carrierwave should be able to duplicate the thumbnail. Regardless, it sounds like you've got this covered. Glad I could help.